# Turning form input into text in a file using php

Tags: php, html, fputs

I have a HTML form with the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="/subscribe/subscribe.php">
<p><input type="text" name "Email" value="your@email.com" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

I have the `subscribe.php` file with the following code:

```
# CONTENT
$email = $_POST['Email'];

# SAVE A COPY
$mailcopyfile = 'mailcopyfile.txt';
$fp = fopen($mailcopyfile, "a"); 
fputs($fp, $now . $email . ", ");
fclose($fp);
```

But in my mailcopyfile.txt all I get is commas for every new form submission like:

```
, , , , ,
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the emails show?

Comment: And why doesn't the time show in the text file with the $now command?

Comment: I thought I could just call it without defining it, first time writing php. But, it is not needed since this form should only hold emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your form/input line:

```
<p><input type="text" name "Email" value="your@email.com" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;"></p>
```

after the name parameter is no equal sign. So i think this is the problem why there is no value in your text file.

```
<p><input type="text" name="Email" value="your@email.com" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;"></p>
```